# Top 5 and Other in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following code which returns the top 5  by NetTotal :-

```
SELECT
  *
  FROM (SELECT
      b.BROKERAGE_NAME,
      SUM(s.STATEMENT_NET) AS NetTotal
    FROM TBLSTATEMENTSNEW s
    LEFT JOIN TBLBROKERAGESNEW b
      ON s.BROKERAGE_ID = b.ID
    WHERE s.STATEMENT_DATE BETWEEN To_date('01-AUG-2017') AND To_date('05-AUG-2017')
    GROUP BY b.BROKERAGE_NAME
    ORDER BY NetTotal DESC) st
WHERE rownum <= 5
ORDER BY rownum;
```

Is it possible to have the non-Top5 NetTotals summed as a sixth row, with a BROKERAGE_NAME of "Other"?

I would like the output to be :-

```
BROKERAGE_NAME  NetTotal
--------------  --------
Bro1                 222
Bro2                 333
Bro3                 444
Bro4                 555
Bro5                 666
Other            3143514
```

Comment: can you add a desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sub-query factoring clause to re-use the ordered query you have generated:

```
WITH totals AS (
  SELECT ROWNUM AS rn,
         t.*
  FROM   (
    SELECT b.BROKERAGE_NAME,
           SUM(s.STATEMENT_NET) AS NetTotal
    FROM   TBLSTATEMENTSNEW s
           LEFT JOIN TBLBROKERAGESNEW b
           ON s.BROKERAGE_ID = b.ID
    WHERE s.STATEMENT_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2017-08-01' AND DATE '2017-08-05'
    GROUP BY b.BROKERAGE_NAME
    ORDER BY NetTotal DESC
  ) t
)
SELECT BROKERAGE_NAME,
       NetTotal
FROM   totals
WHERE  rn <= 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Other',
       SUM( NetTotal )
FROM   totals
WHERE  rn > 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rn <= 5 THEN rn
            ELSE 6
       END row_num,
       CASE WHEN rn <= 5 THEN brokerage_name
            ELSE 'Other'
       END brokerage_name,
       SUM(nettotal) AS nettotal
FROM   (SELECT b.brokerage_name,
           SUM(s.statement_net) AS nettotal,
               row_number() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(s.statement_net) DESC) rn
      FROM   tblstatementsnew s
               LEFT JOIN tblbrokeragesnew b ON s.brokerage_id = b.id
      WHERE  s.statement_date BETWEEN to_date('01-AUG-2017', 'dd-MON-yyyy') AND to_date('05-AUG-2017', 'dd-MON-yyyy')
      GROUP  BY b.brokerage_name
      ORDER  BY nettotal DESC) st
GROUP BY CASE WHEN rn <= 5 THEN rn
              ELSE 6
         END row_num,
         CASE WHEN rn <= 5 THEN brokerage_name
              ELSE 'Other'
         END;
```

You should test each solution to see which one works best for your data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the analytic `row_number()` function:

```
SELECT case when rn <= 5 then BROKERAGE_NAME else 'Other' end
     , sum(NetTotal) 
  FROM (SELECT BROKERAGE_NAME, NetTotal, row_number() over (order by NetTotal DESC) rn
          FROM (SELECT b.BROKERAGE_NAME
                     , SUM(s.STATEMENT_NET) AS NetTotal
                  FROM TBLSTATEMENTSNEW s
                       LEFT JOIN TBLBROKERAGESNEW b
                              ON s.BROKERAGE_ID = b.ID
                 WHERE s.STATEMENT_DATE BETWEEN To_date('01-AUG-2017') AND To_date('05-AUG-2017')
                 GROUP BY b.BROKERAGE_NAME
                ) 
       )
group by case when rn <= 5 then BROKERAGE_NAME else 'Other' end
ORDER BY min(case when rn <= 5 then rn else 6 end);
```

If you need to cater for the unlikely (but possible) case where one of the brokerages happens to be called "Other" then this will take care of that:

```
SELECT BROKERAGE_NAME, NetTotal
  FROM (SELECT case when rn <= 5 then BROKERAGE_NAME else 'Other' end BROKERAGE_NAME
             , case when rn <= 5 then rn else 6 end as rn2
             , sum(NetTotal) NetTotal
          FROM (SELECT BROKERAGE_NAME, NetTotal, row_number() over (order by NetTotal DESC) rn
                  FROM (SELECT b.BROKERAGE_NAME
                             , SUM(s.STATEMENT_NET) AS NetTotal
                          FROM TBLSTATEMENTSNEW s
                               LEFT JOIN TBLBROKERAGESNEW b
                                    ON s.BROKERAGE_ID = b.ID
                         WHERE s.STATEMENT_DATE BETWEEN To_date('01-AUG-2017') AND To_date('05-AUG-2017')
                         GROUP BY b.BROKERAGE_NAME
                       )
                ) 
          group by case when rn <= 5 then BROKERAGE_NAME else 'Other' end BROKERAGE_NAME
                 , case when rn <= 5 then rn else 6 end as rn2
          ORDER BY rn2);
```

Comment: What happens if you have a brokerage name of `Other`?

Comment: @MT0 Then you would be silly to use 'Other' for other brokerages!